# Proper way to Implement a Birthday Class in Object Oriented Python

Tags: python-3.x, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have the following class

```
class Dob:
    def __init__(self):
        self.welcome_text = ""
    
    #Computes DOB
    def calc_dob(self):
        pass

    #Get User Input
    def get_input(self, msg):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.welcome_text)
        total_days = self.calc_dob()
        return str(total_days)
```

And calls it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Dob())
```

Initially I thought this is OK but importing it into PyCharm IDE, it shows warning that methods *calc_dob* and *get_input* could be static.

Following the IDE's suggestion, it moves the methods outside of the class.

All that is left is the *__repr__* method .That makes me think something is wrong with the Class above.

Is the code OK, and I should just rather mark the methods with *@staticmethod* annotation? **or** my idea isn't Object Oriented and how can I make it Object Oriented.

Any help will be appreciated please.

Comment: The reason why pycharm "complains" is because `self` is not used in the methods `calc_dob` or `get_input`. Once you fill out these functions it will be Ok! I would also recommend writing the class as `DayOfBirth` following [Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Please note that on Code Review, we review code that does what it's supposed to do. Your code seems like it's missing 3/4 of its intended features, so it's too early in the process to get a proper review. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Felt bad, and it's all about same bad energy around Stack Exchange. Everything that's required to test in Isolation the Above class is right there and redundant stuffs removed for brevity. The question is about and tagged Object Oriented analysis, so it's about the design being proper and object oriented or not.   Just Someone from some part of the world who couldn't be of help just come from nowhere and feels the best is to Close leaving some silly comments. Horrible!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of the above class is wrong and I can see now. A **birthday** Object should hold date and relevant data as Instance Variables, and it shouldn't be responsible for printing to the console.

I/O should be done when calling the class. And as we have a Date Object already in the standard library, a function would do.

It's  bad coming from a Java background where everything has to go inside a Class,  didn't think twice before constructing one when a mere *package level function* will do.